# generate pdf with Arabic and latine words using TCPDF issue

Tags: php, pdf, utf-8, character-encoding, tcpdf

I have an issue with showing Arabic words in a pdf using tcpdf library.
I used this [example](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_018/) but it works only if I used `$pdf-Cell()` method, when I use `$pdf->writeHTML()` it shows '???', and I need to use writeHTML().

Here is the code

```
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false, false, true);
    $template = file_get_contents("file_template.html");

    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 10, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
    $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->SetPrintFooter(true);
    $lg = Array();
    $lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
    $lg['a_meta_dir'] = 'rtl';
    $lg['a_meta_language'] = 'ar';
    $lg['w_page'] = 'page';
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->setRTL(false);
    $pdf->SetFont('aealarabiya', '', 18);
    $data = str_replace('{' . $key . '}', trim($dictionary["$key"]), $html);
    $template = str_replace("{Data}", $data, $template);
    $pdf->writeHTML($template, true, 0, true, 0);
    $file = 'file-' . date('dmY-His') . '.pdf';
    return $pdf->Output($file, "D");
```

PS: The data cames from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was in CSS level, I was using `font-family: serif` to all the tags in the HTML file, and `serif` font is not supported with Arabic.

When I changed it, it worked just fine.